# Maximum Hamming distance among a list of padded strings

Tags: code-golf, string

The Hamming distance between two strings of *equal* length is the number of positions at which the corresponding characters are different. If the strings are not of equal length, the Hamming distance is not defined.

#### Challenge

Write a program or function that finds the largest Hamming distance from among all pairs of strings from a list of strings, padded as required according to the rules described below.

The characters will be from within `a-zA-Z0-9`.

The strings may not be equal in length, so for each comparison the shorter string has to be padded as follows:

- wrap the string from the beginning as many times as needed to match the required length
- change the cases of the letters each *odd time* wrapping (1st, 3rd, 5th, etc.)
- leave things outside `a-zA-Z` unchanged when wrapping

For example, let's say you need to pad the 5 character string `ab9Cd` so that it ends up with 18 characters. You would end up with:

```
ab9CdAB9cDab9CdAB9
     ^^^^^     ^^^
```

with `^` added underneath the 1st and 3rd wraps to highlight to case changes.

#### Input/Output

Input/output format is flexible. You can assume the input has at least two strings, and that all strings will have at least one character.

The output is an integer.

#### Rules

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf). Standard rules apply.

#### Test cases

```
[ "a", "b" ] => 1
[ "a", "b", "c" ] => 1
[ "a", "a", "c" ] => 1
[ "abc", "abcd" ] => 1
[ "abc12D5", "abC34d3", "ABC14dabc23DAbC89d"] => 17  
[ "a", "Aaa", "AaaA", "aAaAa", "aaaaaaaaaaaaaa", "AAaAA", "aAa" ] => 8
["AacaAc", "Aab"] => 2
```

#### Reference implementation

I tested the examples with (completely ungolfed) R code that you can [try here](https://tio.run/##fVJNT@MwFLznV5icHClFJAVpkeghFDhx2wsCoci1TRvJcSzbFYEVv72M7RYtIiV5ip1543lftjvDBLmakZet5r4bNB0L8i8jRLeuCrjmG2bp@FQ9Fwmt/0friMK6F5pOLCInaRDieqZUOOC8dUZ1PiqVJM@LJ2yeI0kxu5aBFPQiotsvLKgB@yBSOfmLav2LajWlWgXVlPwgRPtqmQmeUJi3NGez92b2mEMUC36wi2H39Qa6kbFzhjkvz6iVhnIaOeWXYlESJfXab06HrSeLQwqA@aAUMyhpEdKGIqd7zTKlXmQfWbZhfd/p9dSA0niO9zUN6niHYFb6rdXUbXsKtZMFzhQxLO6EkKI9En0PU7DwW2RZz8bWbCZvUQBTBwABeAiAHA3T4nRtOwiUBIY0oegad8e4H6xDV@6a@7@3@24jAO0ZOCNFi9QbfShJVZLvaaKpGhYq2KWMMA@SszDDVU6A/0Tx4ZMuNu1a8ehccTHhquqbi@Rezs/FPN6d62V1LuCr5zfNavnnUkxGa9hhaaJAgzduvj2RAteBE6R2u08) to compare any other examples you might try out with your code.

Comment: *change the cases of the letters each odd time wrapping* – Oh boy, this requirement is going to be a pain for my solution... I like the challenge, though, so +1

Comment: Suggested test case: `["AacaAc", "Aab"] => 2`. A purposed golf to my Jelly answer would have failed that case, but would have passes all the other ones.

Comment: @ngm Excellent challenge! +1

Answer (score 7):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 20 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jellylanguage/wiki/Code-page)

Not really happy with it. Should be golfable, even to ~15 bytes perhaps.

```
LÞŒcµṁ/sḢL$ŒsÐeFn)§Ṁ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9/n8Lyjk5IPbX24s1G/@OGORT4qRycVH56Q6paneWj5w50N////j1ZKTEo2NHIxVdJRADKdjU1SjEFMRydnQ5MUoJyRsYtjkrOFZYpSLAA)

or [Check out a test suite!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9/n8Lyjk5IPbX24s1G/@OGORT4qRycVH56Q6paneWj5w50N/w@3P2pa4/7/f3S0UqKSjoJSklKsDpcCnAMkkpFFElFEkpLBYknJKQgRQyMXU4ios7FJijGI6ejkbGiSApQzMnZxTHK2sExBNtIxEUY5gvU5AiGYgQLASoBSMDVKsbEA)

#### Explanation

```
LÞŒcµṁ/sḢL$ŒsÐeFn)§Ṁ    Full program or monadic link. N = input.                     | Example: ["abc12D5", "abC34d3", "ABC14dabc23DAbC89d"]
LÞ                      Sort N by length.                                            | [['a', 'b', 'c', '1', '2', 'D', '5'], ['a', 'b', 'C', '3', '4', 'd', '3'], ['A', 'B', 'C', '1', '4', 'd', 'a', 'b', 'c', '2', '3', 'D', 'A', 'b', 'C', '8', '9', 'd']] (in Jelly, strings are list of characters)
  Œc                    Unordered pairs: [x, y] for all distinct x, y in N.          | [[['a', 'b', 'c', '1', '2', 'D', '5'], ['a', 'b', 'C', '3', '4', 'd', '3']], [['a', 'b', 'c', '1', '2', 'D', '5'], ['A', 'B', 'C', '1', '4', 'd', 'a', 'b', 'c', '2', '3', 'D', 'A', 'b', 'C', '8', '9', 'd']], [['a', 'b', 'C', '3', '4', 'd', '3'], ['A', 'B', 'C', '1', '4', 'd', 'a', 'b', 'c', '2', '3', 'D', 'A', 'b', 'C', '8', '9', 'd']]]
                        Here, by distinct, I mean at different positions.            |
    µ            )      Map with a monadic link.                                     |
     ṁ/                 Mold x like y. That is, cycle x until it reaches length y.   | [['a', 'b', 'c', '1', '2', 'D', '5'], ['a', 'b', 'c', '1', '2', 'D', '5', 'a', 'b', 'c', '1', '2', 'D', '5', 'a', 'b', 'c', '1'], ['a', 'b', 'C', '3', '4', 'd', '3', 'a', 'b', 'C', '3', '4', 'd', '3', 'a', 'b', 'C', '3']]
       sḢL$             Split into chunks of x's length.                             | [[['a', 'b', 'c', '1', '2', 'D', '5']], [['a', 'b', 'c', '1', '2', 'D', '5'], ['a', 'b', 'c', '1', '2', 'D', '5'], ['a', 'b', 'c', '1']], [['a', 'b', 'C', '3', '4', 'd', '3'], ['a', 'b', 'C', '3', '4', 'd', '3'], ['a', 'b', 'C', '3']]]
           ŒsÐe         Swap the case of even-indexed chunks (1-indexed).            | [[['a', 'b', 'c', '1', '2', 'D', '5']], [['a', 'b', 'c', '1', '2', 'D', '5'], ['A', 'B', 'C', '1', '2', 'd', '5'], ['a', 'b', 'c', '1']], [['a', 'b', 'C', '3', '4', 'd', '3'], ['A', 'B', 'c', '3', '4', 'D', '3'], ['a', 'b', 'C', '3']]]
               F        Flatten.                                                     | [['a', 'b', 'c', '1', '2', 'D', '5'], ['a', 'b', 'c', '1', '2', 'D', '5', 'A', 'B', 'C', '1', '2', 'd', '5', 'a', 'b', 'c', '1'], ['a', 'b', 'C', '3', '4', 'd', '3', 'A', 'B', 'c', '3', '4', 'D', '3', 'a', 'b', 'C', '3']]
                n       Vectorized inequality with y.                                | [[[0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]], [[1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]], [[1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]]]
                  §     After ending the map, sum each bool (0 or 1) array.          | [[5], [17], [14]]
                   Ṁ    Maximum.                                                     | 17
```

Comment: I'm totally not familiar with Jelly, but I think you can omit `LÞ` and still get the same maximum at the end.

Comment: @ChasBrown Ugh, no, I *should* need that. Otherwise, instead of padding the shortest to the length of the longest one, `ṁ/` would instead trim the longest to the length of the shortest one in some cases, which is not what we want.... I guess the test cases are too well chosen (and this is a rather unfortunate coincidence)...

Comment: @ChasBrown As an example, try `["AacaAc", "Aab"]`.

Comment: Ah yes, I see... I need to learn me some more Jelly... :)

Answer (score 5):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 86 bytes

```python
lambda a:max(sum(x!=y for x,y in zip((s+s.swapcase())*len(t),t))for s in a for t in a)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY9dC4IwFIav61esq201ArWgBIOl/8K8OPODBL9wi7Q/b9tCsR3YHp7znsHpRvVsG3cqgsdUQS0yQODXMBD5qsmwC0ZUtD0a2IjKBn3KjhB5kEf5hi4FmRNK91XeEEWZotQkpcmBHVIW6WQYDMcxBswQFjhhaGF9pSsBayFSq0QKi3Dc6PyToXfKPIP8HjqnTPdcL@IivFyz1X8c5ofbMa7Lwt@xEd2aMzhJ/O2m68tGIWA4uGFWEL3L9AU)

Given two strings, `s,t`, `zip((s+s.swapcase())*len(t),t))` will be a list of tuples of length `len(t)` since `zip` truncates to the shortest iterable. If `len(s)<len(t)`, then this "pads out" `s` with the desired case swapping and we calculate the `sum` of differing characters.

If `len(t)<=len(s)`, then the resulting `sum` will be less than or equal to the `sum` if we were evaluating `t,s`; so it has no effect on the resulting `max` in that case.

Comment: You can use `y!=` instead of `!=y` to save 1 byte

Comment: @Mr. Xcoder: Thx, but I ended up drastically reworking my solution...

Answer (score 3):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 111 bytes

```javascript
a=>a.map(m=S=>a.map(s=>B(S).map((c,k)=>m=(c^(c=B(s)[k%(l=s.length)])^(k/l&c>9)<<5&&++x)<m?m:x,x=0)),B=Buffer)|m
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##rdBBa8IwFAfw@z5FCKzkYW1Xq0xH05HWb@BRKqRJ61yTVowbPey7d1mkhx30IL5A8of3@IXkk39zI06H43nadrIaajpwmvJA8yPRdDNGQ9OMbMBlIvwGaKopETsiaEYMbJtnoqgJVNXuzx9QwI40ofJEuoIkWXjeZNJDot/1W@/39AXAz2j2VdfVCX70ILrWdKoKVLcnNdkizLGPcIlRge4pABSGKHq6xtpN3GHfZvnj2VI4uBTywWw0Wy8udB7PZfwXWZZHc2l7s3jNyny5kri4wb5e@QXGx4O5C5hdLvwrN2Jb44x93sVdDr8)

Answer (score 3):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 19 bytes

```
WṁŒsÐeF=ċ0
LÞŒcç/€Ṁ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/z/84c7Go5OKD09IdbM90m3A5XN43tFJyYeX6z9qWvNwZ8P///@jlRKTkg2NXEyVdBSATGdjkxRjENPRydnQJAUoZ2Ts4pjkbGGZohQLAA)

```
LÞŒcç/€Ṁ
LÞ         Sort by length
  Œc       unordered pairs
      €    to each of the pairs
    ç/     find the hamming distance with molding and swapping case (helper link)
       Ṁ   maximum

WṁŒsÐeF=ċ0
W            wrap the shorter string
 ṁ           repeat this string once for each character in the second string
    Ðe       for every other repeated string
  Œs         swap case
      F      flatten
       =     characterwise equality check between the two strings. If the first
             string is longer, the leftover characters are appended to the result.
             e.g. 'abABab' and 'xbA' give [0,1,1,'B','a','b']
        ċ0   count the number of 0s, giving the Hamming distance.
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), <s>89</s> 82 bytes

Creates the cross-product of the input list against itself before calculating the Hamming distance of each pair, using a duplication method similar to [Chas Brown's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/170586/52194). Ruby can't zip strings together or add booleans without additional overhead, though, so it becomes necessary to iterate through the pair of strings manually instead.

-7 bytes from GB.

```ruby
->a{a.product(a).map{|s,t|(0...w=t.size).count{|i|(s+s.swapcase)[i%w]!=t[i]}}.max}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JcxPC4IwGIDxu5@iDoFSvaQW1MHA9NKlS91M4t2cOPDPcBMrt8@@hK4P/J5@IB9bRk@7PeOEIPquGKhy0YMGxaTlRml3BwBjpEDyL/OAdkOrJs21K9cS5IiComRexldjvoxUxnNjZvw2VizK7P5IrzdgSKtXzVv2v9a6Blp1jTC5RUL9ID04SJJwX4ROfEn8fTHXIExjkhxPxQ8)

Comment: [82 bytes](https://tio.run/##JcxPC4IwGIDxu5@iDoFSvaQW1MHA9NKlS91M4t2cOPDPcBMrt8@@hK4P/J5@IB9bRk@7PeOEIPquGKhy0YMGxaTlRml3BwBjpEDyL/OAdkOrJs21K9cS5IiComRexldjvoxUxnNjZvw2VizK7P5IrzdgSKtXzVv2v9a6Blp1jTC5RUL9ID04SJJwX4ROfEn8fTHXIExjkhxPxQ8)

Answer (score 2):

## [Java 10](http://jdk.java.net/), <del>748</del> <del>740</del> <del>667</del> <del>666</del> 616 bytes

This has to be the most dense and unreadable, yet the longest golf I ever came up with.

Call method `h(String[])` with an explicit array (no var args): eg,

```
h(new String[] {"a", "b", "c"});
```

returns `1`.

```
char e(boolean w,char c){return(char)(w&(64<c&c<91|96<c&c<123)?c^32:c);}String p(String s,int l){var p="";int m=s.length(),n=l/m,r=l%m,i=0,j=0;var w=1<0;for(;i<n;++i,w=!w)for(char c:s.toCharArray())p+=e(w,c);for(;j<r;)p+=e(w,s.charAt(j++));return p;}int d(String s,String t){int l=s.length(),n=0,i=0;for(;i<l;)if(s.charAt(i)!=t.charAt(i++))++n;return n;}int h(String s,String t){int l=s.length(),m=t.length();return l>m?d(s,p(t,l)):l<m?d(p(s,m),t):d(s,t);}int h(String[]s){int l=s.length,i=0,j;int[]n=new int[l*l];for(;i<l;++i)for(j=i;++j<l;)n[i*l+j]=h(s[i],s[j]);return java.util.Arrays.stream(n).max().getAsInt();}
```

You can [Try It Online](https://tio.run/##nVJdb9owFH0uv8KNtMq3yTK@Vg2CV2X0oXvuIzDJcVLizDFRbEorxm9ndj5ArNrEcKT43Ot7zznXSUZf6Mcs/rlngiqFHtG2s2cpLVGCo9VKJFSijVclGGzLRK9LiW0IeHOD74YTdsMmo96v0V2Fev0B3LMfg/6YQbB70iWXS1TgBiiPS40EbF8MXUEcJ7BxTpQvErnUKQZPEvEp90oiPuQeJ10vI93AVm9Ib9INnlclDvhEBq7LvQ253oDN1O7GyterqYFhWdI3DFC4JMHGO9Rt2aQM2pzybU@ocea6AEE9FiqCnfUTH@02QMO2Mn5qtGsNtpZEAPwZH3g5XBN9CKyI68pWR9Y66Vk6ueFpg5ZAfM3vY6y8AmtPAIzFxMaFyeTgaRjbMw2nKrOF@pO9vmD7DWYLSWSyQRaKW7E4TmUuurrjjHCDMzunnPFb4WYLkmI14wtPzbLFwVpmfid/rbnwq8@gfKXLhOZYgp/TVwz@MtGh@i61mWa371wV60hwhpSm2mwvKx6jnHJ5MI1ouVRgfsqrq0eUIoKszUfTbBJPb0onub9aa78w1VpI7KQ0z03jAzeMkiV47tC546G5E80dMO0OclHqp9jSHDS2DjU1TuTs4CJiu7Fz@M2LXSRCzxahl4hErJGJWPxviYhVIqbuvyV6/YfPrcx0MIwHdRB@m/aGsTnvDx7CaPpl1Dow3Oj9@psty15bq7gtfM980d2H9AjCZoDQPA08WU2hOT5WXjBO5Z62W1jNZSUrcLKqEivX1DQT7jq7zv43)!

#### Ungolfed and commented:

```
// Encode the character (swap case)
char e(boolean w, char c) {
    return (char) (w & (64 < c & c < 91 | 96 < c & c < 123) ? c ^ 32 : c);
}

// Pad the string to desired length
String p(String s, int l) {
    var p = "";
    int m = s.length(), n = l / m, r = l % m, i = 0, j = 0;
    var w = 1 < 0;
    for (; i < n; ++i, w = !w)
        for (char c : s.toCharArray())
            p += e(w, c);
    for (; j < r;)
        p += e(w, s.charAt(j++));
    return p;
}

// Calculate the actual hamming distance between two same-length strings
int d(String s, String t) {
    int l = s.length(), n = 0, i = 0;
    for (; i < l;)
        if (s.charAt(i) != t.charAt(i++))
            ++n;
    return n;
}
// Pad the strings as needed and return their hamming distance
int h(String s, String t) {
    int l = s.length(), m = t.length();
    return l > m ? d(s, p(t, l)) : l < m ? d(p(s, m), t) : d(s, t);
}

    // Dispatch the strings and gather their hamming distances, return the max
int h(String[] s) {
    int l = s.length, i = 0, j;
    int[] n = new int[l * l];
    for (; i < l; ++i)
        for (j = i; ++j < l;)
            n[i * l + j] = h(s[i], s[j]);
    return java.util.Arrays.stream(n).max().getAsInt();
}
```

I *know* a better solution can be achieved, especially for the string pairing part.

**EDIT**: shave off 8 bytes by changing the size of the int array in `hammingDistance()` to the square of the numbe of strings given. It also fixes an `ArrayIndexOutOfBounds` thrown in one of the test cases.

**EDIT 2**: Saved 33 bytes thanks to [Kevin Cruijssen's comments](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/170581/maximum-hamming-distance-among-a-list-of-padded-strings#comment411969_170612): class declaration removed, names shortened to 1 char, operators changed, etc.

**EDIT 3**: Save 1 byte and reach Satan-approved score by changing method with var-arg to array.

**EDIT 4**: Save another 50 bytes thanks to [Kevin Cruijssen](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/170581/maximum-hamming-distance-among-a-list-of-padded-strings#comment411976_170612), again: update Java version from 8 to 10 to use `var` keyword, removed `StringBuilder` instance, etc.

Comment: I don't have a lot of time, but some basic things to golf: Drop the class, only the methods is enough. Change all method and variable names to single bytes.. So instead of `hammingDistance` use `d` or some other unused variable. Most of your `&&` can be `&` and `||` can be `|`. `c^' '` can be `c^32`. `boolean w = false;` can be `boolean w=0>1;`. `i=0` in the loop initialization can be removed and change the `,i,j` to `,i=0,j`. `++j` can be removed and `++` can be added to the `.charAt(j++)`. `.toString()` can be `+""`. `for(j=i+1;j<l;++j)` can be `for(j=0;++j<l;)`. Etc. etc.

Comment: [Tips for golfing in Java](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/6671/tips-for-golfing-in-java) and [Tips for golfing in <all languages>](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/5285/tips-for-golfing-in-all-languages) might be interesting to read through as well. :)

Comment: Thanks! That's some nice byte-lifting. Thanks for the links too, I'm taking a look at it and will edit asap!

Comment: Upvoted for the Satan-approved score. xD Some more small things: `StringBuilder` can be `StringBuffer` (if you switch to Java 10 it could be `var b=new StringBuffer(l);`. The `boolean` and `char` can then also be `var`. If you don't have Java 10 locally, [it is available on TIO](https://tio.run/##y0osS9TNSsn@DwQA)). In addition, `for(;i<n;++i){for(char c:s.toCharArray())b.append(e(w,c));w=!w;}` can be `for(;i++<n;w=!w)for(char c:s.toCharArray())b.append(e(w,c));`. And I'm pretty sure you can remove the `StringBuffer` completely and just use `String` and `+=` instead of `append`.

Comment: Man, some many months of clean code and good coding practices made me forget how to even golf! I'll update my answer and include TIO.

Comment: [459 bytes](https://tio.run/##lVDNbuMgGHwVL1IjPpm40e7NhETV9pCDc7JvTSoR6tbYmFiGxGos76tnwfmpellpLzADzHwzlPzIp@VbdRaKGxOs@rMoeBvkWGobdGQkAvo2t4dWY08Bd/PZ5LdDXNi8jaRJcusAFrAUr79@xgLokNpW6o@gwVdgiPdT0B@dX8MQop7XzEQq1x@2wEA0U4816diMvu9bTPV0upjRjv3pwHOvE7GJ7N5Pfmpb/okBmpDl2KWEUaMeWE3VqLvdmMhHfrJYAdBLiaChgx9eXLO9bA30Y7p7GiKZIiWp2IycSELWl0Ty4uxxySQNw3KuKPTXhikzL3JLMreVW3pyNRKW3tvRNcu@SMqS@XrpPoesIU5pxpKFpxlJIM7GYd@0yWVw5c6ubRL44fzuZDIJw9OiWp7iig63mg6em8NOSREYy63bjnv5FtRc6ntzDv0qKJjOu2Dlc30am9fR/mCjxj2wSmNU8Lp2b5@lM9EixxvEN4hs0G6DgKGwiArs5TfHHnFE0A4N8N92bhX/NiVIjMbDcP4L "Java (JDK) – Try It Online")

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), <s>33</s> 29 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
Ćü)€é©εćDš«s`g∍}®€¤‚ø€ζ€€Ë_Oà
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f//SNvhPZqPmtYcXnlo5bmtR9pdji48tLo4If1RR2/toXVAiUNLHjXMOrwDpAREgOjueP/DC/7/j1ZKTEo2NHIxVdIBspyNTVKMgSxHJ2dDkxSgjJGxi2OSs4VlilIsAA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/W/u5ulir6TwqG2SgpL9/yNth/doPmpac3jloZXnth5pdzm68NDq4oT0Rx29tYfWASUOLXnUMOvwDiDr3DYgAVLaHe9/eMF/nf/RSolKOkpJSrFcMJaOUjKcl4jgJSWD@EnJKTCuoZGLKVjI2dgkxRjIcnRyNjRJAcoYGbs4JjlbWKbAzXFMhJKOIB2OQAiiUQBIHigBVQDWCTIQYqkLxKIUY6NUpVgA).

Can most likely be halved in byte-count, but it works..

**Explanation:**

```python
Ć           # Enclose the input-list (adding the first item to the end of the list)
            #  i.e. ['ABC1','abcD','abCd32e'] → ['ABC1','abcD','abCd32e','ABC1']
 ü)         # Pair-vectorize each of them
            #  i.e. ['ABC1','abcD','abCd32e','ABC1']
            #   → [['ABC1','abcD'],['abcD','abCd32e'],['abCd32e','ABC1']]
   €é       # Sort each pair by length
            #  i.e. [['ABC1','abcD'],['abcD','abCd32e'],['abCd32e','ABC1']]
            #   → [['ABC1','abcD'],['abcD','abCd32e'],['ABC1','abCd32e']]
     ©      # Store this list in the register to re-use later on
ε        }  # Map each inner list in this list to:
 ć          # Head extracted
            #  i.e. ['abcD','abCd32e'] → 'abcD' and ['abCd32e']
  Dš        # Duplicate it, and swap the capitalization of the copy
            #  i.e. 'abcD' → 'ABCd'
    «       # Then merge it together
            #  i.e. 'abcD' and 'ABCd' → 'abcDABCd'
     s`     # Swap so the tail-list is at the top of the stack, and get it's single item
            #  i.e. ['abCd32e'] → 'abCd32e'
       g    # Get the length of that
            #  i.e. 'abCd32e' → 7
        ∍   # Extend/shorten the string to that length
            #  i.e. 'abcDABCd' and 7 → 'abcDABC'
®           # Get the saved list from the register again
 €¤         # Get the tail from each
            #  i.e. [['ABC1','abcD'],['abcD','abCd32e'],['abCd32e','ABC1']]
            #   → ['abcD','abCd32e','abCd32e']
   ‚        # Pair it with the other list
            #  i.e. ['ABC1','abcDABC','ABC1abc'] and ['abcD','abCd32e','abCd32e']
            #   → [['ABC1','abcDABC','ABC1abc'],['abcD','abCd32e','abCd32e']]
    ø       # Zip it, swapping rows / columns
            #  i.e. [['ABC1','abcDABC','ABC1abc'],['abcD','abCd32e','abCd32e']]
            #   → [['ABC1','abcD'],['abcDABC','abCd32e'],['ABC1abc','abCd32e']]
     €ζ     # And then zip each pair again
            #  i.e. [['ABC1','abcD'],['abcDABC','abCd32e'],['ABC1abc','abCd32e']]
            #   → [['Aa','Bb','Cc','1D'],['aa','bb','cC','Dd','A3','B2','Ce'],['Aa','Bb','CC','1d','a3','b2','ce']]
€           # Then for each inner list
 €          #  And for each inner string
  Ë         #   Check if all characters are the same
            #    i.e. 'aa' → 1
            #    i.e. 'cC' → 0
   _        # And inverse the booleans
            #  i.e. [['Aa','Bb','Cc','1D'],['aa','bb','cC','Dd','A3','B2','Ce'],['Aa','Bb','CC','1d','a3','b2','ce']]
            #   → [[1,1,1,1],[0,0,1,1,1,1,1],[1,1,0,1,1,1,1]]
O           # Then sum each inner list
            #  i.e. [[1,1,1,1],[0,0,1,1,1,1,1],[1,1,0,1,1,1,1]] → [4,5,6]
 à          # And take the max as result
            #  i.e. [4,5,6] → 6
```

Answer (score 1):

## Java 11, 387 bytes

```java
a->{int l=a.length,i=l,t,j=0,C[]=new int[l];var p=new String[l][2];for(;i-->0;p[i][0]=a[t>0?i:j],p[i][1]=a[t>0?j:i])t=a[i].length()<a[j=-~i%l].length()?1:0;i=0;for(var P:p){var s="";for(var x:P[0].getBytes())s+=(char)(x>64&x<91|x>96&x<123?x^32:x);for(P[0]=repeat(P[0]+s,t=P[1].length()).substring(0,t);t-->0;)if(P[0].charAt(t)!=P[1].charAt(t))C[i]++;i++;}for(int c:C)j=c>j?c:j;return j;}
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##bVNRb9MwEH7nV5hIMFtNvaQdE0vmVlnHA0iMSeMtBMlxvM0hTav4MlqN8sgP4CfyR4rtZC1TSRTn7ru773y@c8kf@LAsvm1FxbVGH7mqH18gpGqQzS0XEl1Z1QFI4BtoVH2XZoiT2MCbF2bRwEEJdIVqxNCWDyeP1rdinFayvoN7X7HKB79kgT9LM1bL75YsrbL4gTdo6YCet8rSURbfLhocq@FwEsTLVGVpkDGewiSYqqjMfAeFT1AZqYyAUVTWp8PknKclG/5Ur6o9Ng2jIFYscOQ273W0JI9W0Mzzdugqujbp6J2EizVIjQnRA4bFPW8IXk1OT16vzs/CH6vJ2amRwtF4uvo6HkUr4ghsKGvkUnJw8kD7wK7NXne7IFS3uXa14sAHEoOrkqhbF0BtogQwkJdd3E4nM1PgYBAr821sLteOaEZKJiblVERl3EhomxqV8WYb27Ys27wybem787BQBZqb5v7bwq6zpk7AHvd8L/dcV59DvicOYf4fOBfWkIviAA9Hl2@cbTY@KcZGSi5m4UlhLKPxZZLP3p4VhykS3q@JDU3Ma//PHms3ht7hOYVN0e3nsktdjEfSO5hady4uojsXSunuYG7WGuScLlqgS2ODqsaluS20BVXRpGn4WlNYdHGYk4GH/vz6jbxBTYVR96mOj9G7eVtxkAX6YAhQGB7pfuRpPy@Gnvgol4K3Wj55IaXrI0CLGn1@/wmtJSCs@Vyi3MzmUCxaE7OvpONDPV@vmVnz3dXlc@feFdaPyv7iYSvaYUs7v4zYfVXm@mPvS@D5hqYvZ7P9Cw) (NOTE: Since Java 11 isn't on TIO yet, `String.repeat(int)` has been emulated as `repeat(String,int)` for the same byte-count.)

**Explanation:**

```java
a->{                      // Method with String-array parameter and integer return-type
  int l=a.length,         //  Length of the input-array
      i=l,                //  Index-integer, starting at the length
      t,j=0,              //  Temp-integers
      C[]=new int[l];     //  Count-array the same size as the input
  var p=new String[l][2]; //  String-pairs array the same size as the input
  for(;i-->0              //  Loop `i` in the range [`l`, 0)
      ;                   //    After every iteration:
       p[i][0]=           //     Set the first String of the pair at index `i` to:
               a[t>0?i:j],//      The smallest of the `i`'th or `j`'th Strings of the input-array
       p[i][1]=           //     And set the second String of the pair at index `i` to:
               a[t>0?j:i])//      The largest of the `i`'th or `j`'th Strings of the input-array
    t=a[i].length()<      //    If the length of the `i`'th item is smaller than
      a[j=-~i%l].length()?//    the length of the `i+1`'th item
                          //    (and set `j` to this `i+1` with wrap-around to 0 for the last item
       1                  //     Set `t` to 1 as flag
      :                   //    Else:
       0;                 //     Set `t` to 0 as flag
                          //  We've now created the String pairs, where each pair is sorted by length
  i=0;                    //  Reset `i` to 0
  for(var P:p){           //  Loop over the pairs
    var s="";             //   Temp-String starting empty
    for(var x:P[0].getBytes())
                          //   Loop over the characters of the first String of the pair
      s+=                 //    Append the temp-String with:
         (char)(x>64&x<91|x>96&x<123?
                         //      If the current character is a letter:
           x^32          //       Swap it's case before appending it to `s`
         :               //      Else (not a letter):
          x);            //       Append it to `s` as is
    for(P[0]=            //    Now replace the first String with:
        repeat(P[0]+s,   //     The first String appended with the case-swapped first String
               t=P[1].length())
                         //     Repeated `t` amount of times,
                         //     where `t` is the length of the second String of the pair
        .substring(0,t); //     And then shorten it to length `t`
        t-->0;)          //    Inner loop over the character of the now same-length Pairs
      if(P[0].charAt(t)!=P[1].charAt(t))
                         //     If the characters at the same indices in the pair are not equal
        C[i]++;          //      Increase the counter for this pair by 1
    i++;}                //    After every iteration of the outer loop,
                         //    increase `i` by 1 for the next iteration
  for(int c:C)           //  Now loop over the calculated counts
    j=c>j?c:j;           //   And set `j` to the maximum
  return j;}             //  And finally return this maximum `j` as result
```

Answer (score 1):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 173 bytes

```r
function(x,U=utf8ToInt,N=nchar)max(combn(x,2,function(z,v=z[order(N(z))])sum(U(substr(Reduce(paste0,rep(c(v[1],chartr('A-Za-z','a-zA-Z',v[1])),n<-N(v[2]))),1,n))!=U(v[2]))))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bY7NaoQwFIX3fQrrxly4QtUpTKEuUmfTjYtSNx2GIT8O04VRohkGX97eOLXQ1gRuDuc7OYmdGnE9dud8Ojmjhs/WsCtWuRtO2/f21QxY5kadhQWKMdU20vMUf8IjXvJx31pdW1ayEeAAvWtYxXon@8Gyt1o7VbNO9EP9gLbumGKXfXJAX0o84vGHiMcII5qkI/QUAM1zXFIyJQ2YoAG4z6vFgO9fU1kQihCDUIYBwN1/l4ZaRWIdSTVDqfQKStLd4w0X2UZnXvKXItloYmm247LYPunV17hYDj4XcNqz@LXmCKEl87eK325z709f)

@ngm : I tried my best to golf your code (with my *heavy* customizations of course) but, as you well know, R is not very golfy in manipulating strings :P

Comment: I bet this can be sub 150 bytes, but I'm not sure how just yet.

Comment: @Giuseppe: I suspect that too... but I'm not really good in writing short strings manipulation codes and R doesn't help me very much either :D

Comment: @digEmAll I'm not going to try to solve my own challenge, but few possibilities might include `outer` to get all the combinations, and doing modular arithmetic on the code points in lieu of `chartr`.

Comment: @ngm: possible...I discarded the arithmetic approach because I couldn't find a short solution/formula to change the case for letters without touching the numbers...